# Expected Value based on condition with range.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let's say I'm asked $E[X\mid Y<1]$, where, $0<X<2$ and $0<Y<2.$ I know that I need $f_{X\mid Y<1.5}.$
My question is, is  $f_{X\mid Y<1.5} = \dfrac{f(x,y)}{\int_0^2\int_0^{1.5}f(x,y)\,dy\,dx}$ OR is it $\dfrac{f(x,y)}{\int_0^{1.5}f_y(y)\,dy}$?

Comment: Are the results different?

Comment: You shouldn't write $f_y(y)$ where you mean $f_Y(y).$ Without distinguishing between capital $Y$ and lower-case $y$ you can't even understand something like $\Pr(Y\le y). \qquad$

Comment: @Callculus, when I've done this 2 different ways, I get the same result, but it was on 2 different problems, which I now can't find. So the reason I'm asking here is to see if this is generalizable

Comment: I would say if the range of X does not depend on Y, et vice versa, then the results are the same.  But not in this case, for instance: $0<X<Y, 0<Y<2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is neither.  It is this:

$$\begin{align}f_{X\mid Y\leqslant 1.5}(x) &=\dfrac{f_X(x)\,\mathsf P(Y\leqslant 1.5\mid X=x)}{\mathsf P(Y\leqslant 1.5)}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{\int_0^{1.5}f_{X,Y}(x,t)\,\mathrm d t}{\int_0^{1.5} f_{Y}(t)\,\mathrm d t}\\[2ex] &=\dfrac{\int_0^{1.5}f_{X,Y}(x,t)\,\mathrm d t}{\int_0^2\int_0^{1.5} f_{X,Y}(s,t)\,\mathrm d t\,\mathrm d s}\end{align}$$

And thus $$\mathsf E(X\mid Y\leqslant 1.5) = \dfrac{\int_0^2\int_0^{1.5} s\, f_{X,Y}(s,t)\,\mathrm d t\,\mathrm d s}{\int_0^2\int_0^{1.5} f_{X,Y}(s,t)\,\mathrm d t\,\mathrm d s}$$